# Running script to many computers at once or apply it to a particular OU computers

Tags: powershell

```
Copy-Item -path '\\Dell\CCTK' -destination C:\CCTK -recurse
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {c:\CCTK\cctk --controlwlanradio=enable}
```

How can I remotely run the above script  to many computers at once or apply it to a particular computer OU

Answer (score 0):

If remoting is enabled on the machines you try to execute this command it is possible to pass the -ComputerName parameter to the Invoke-Command, command. The computername takes multiple values.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer1,Computer2,etc -ScriptBlock {c:\CCTK\cctk --controlwlanradio=enable}
```